# Button looks selected in Angular

Tags: css, angular

In my application when my material dialog pop up, the "X" button to leave the dialog looks selected. If I click inside the dialog, it unselect itself.

[image]

```html
<button mat-icon-button class="close-button" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
  <mat-icon class="close-icon" color="warn">close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.close-button{
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  float: right;
  top:-24px;
  right:-24px;
}
```

How can I make it look normal as soon as I open the dialog ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `autoFocus` attribute to `false`

```js
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogExample, {
    autoFocus: false,
    //other attributes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't selected, but I guess the button is placed inside a dialog and By default on dialog open the first element will have the focus.

If you want to disable this **autoFocus** the following piece of code will help you.

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YourDialogComponent, {
    autoFocus: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the button has a background color, in your css set the background color / background to white or none

Comment: no there is no background color, it's like if it was focused, when I click next to it it goes back to normal

Comment: Using the console in chrome you can see the different states of an element,
go to the elements tab then styles on the right (usually) here you can see :hov. if you click it you can see the states of the buttons. And force different states using this you can see what is giving your button the color.

Comment: It's really hard to inspect as the button goes back to normal as soon as I click inside the console. I found a workaround, I removed the button and only used the icon for my actions. It also looks better so I'll just stick with it.

I forgot to mention, transform / rotates did not work on the button but work on the icon alone.. The button must be bugged or something

Comment: It could indeed be a problem with the material styling overriding your prefferences